# Eclipse e4 Part Not Created Until First Shown

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

I have a part which is a simple list view, which I'm using as a log view. In the `@PostConstruct` method it registers for events to be logged. By default the part is stacked behind another part. I've found that the `@PostConstruct` method is not called until the view is first shown to the user. This means that log events are not logged unless the user has first clicked on the part. This doesn't work for me, as I want the part to contain the full log history, even if the user has never clicked on it.

Have I missed something basic? Is there any way that I can coax e4 to construct the part right from the start? I guess a better way to handle this would be to keep the log event data separately and only viewed through the part. Is there any way to avoid that?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the part created using the injectable part service `EPartService`  -

```
partService.showPart(id, PartState.CREATE);
```

It might be better to put the listeners in a non-UI component which you could start from the life cycle `@PostContextCreate` method.

Comment: Thank you! When I read your answer a month ago I couldn't understand how to implement your suggestion. Coming back to this problem, with fresh eyes, and I understood what you were saying. This has just worked perfectly for me. Sorry for the delay in responding!